# Y-axis limit switch adjustment is way off on new Ender 3 V2 causing motor grinding noise and system lockup

Tags: y-axis

Just received my new Ender 3 v2. When using the Auto Home feature, the Y-axis motor drives the bed as far back as possible then the motor grinds for about 10-15 seconds. The Y-axis limit switch is not being depressed and the limit stop is about .5 inches away from the switch. The control unit locks at this point and must be power cycled to regain control. If I manually depress the limit switch then it appears to act normally.

Clearly either the limit switch is way out of adjustment or the bed is not positioned properly. Can this be fixed or should I send it back as defective?

Comment: DaveS, is it possible that your buildplate is too low now - and it is hitting the motor instead of moving bit further? I you would you like to follow some guidelines, please check these tutorials for many unique great tips in each of them: [(1) Creality Ender 3 assembly and pro build tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me8Qrwh907Q), [(2) Creality Ender-3 V2 assembly and pro build tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTN6jtB5mqk), [(3) Ender 3 easy bed leveling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JSa_r8xgX8) - here including better positioning of the Z-stop.

Comment: Sounds defective.  My Ender 3v2 Y-limit switch is lower than the build plate and stops against the right rear y-axis wheel, not the build plate.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the **buildplate is too low**, and cannot travel all way down  the Y axis, but is hitting into the Y motor enclosure.

If you have screwed the Z-stop to printer's vertical frame, shifting the endstop all the way down, there is even bigger chance for this. So one advice is to **raise the Z-stop** by about a width of wrench key included to the set. Ender 3 V2 has a bit taller glass plate comparing to previous model.

That is not my idea, I just repeat that after the author of ["Tomb of 3D Printed Horrors" youtube tutorials](https://youtu.be/JTN6jtB5mqk?t=2071). The author also presented quick method [Ender 3 easy bed leveling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JSa_r8xgX8), including **fine tuning** of the Z-stop position.

Please also note, that there are wires with thermistor taped below the bed with crackling tape (probably capton). So if you raise it too few, you will regularly hear scraping and crackling sounds. Therefore before builtplate leveling, I would advice first to **check the initial height** if it is already safe.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to just bend the brass piece on the switch toward the front of the printer.  Be careful of course, breaking it would be very bad.  That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced my Y-axis belt, I returned everything to its regular place and it started grinding. This was because the build plate is symmetrical but the wheels are a little lower on one side, so flipping around the build plate fixed this for me.